# Cannot change border radius of Material UI DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, material-design

I am struggling to get my DatePicker component from @mui/x-date-pickers and Material UI V5 to have rounded borders.

I would like to have my component look like this.

[image: DatePicker]

I have attempted to create the effect using styled the styled component from Material UI. I know I am meant to be targeting the MUIOutlinedInput styling but I cannot seem to get the syntax right. I was wondering if anyone could offer a suggestion. Below is my failed approach. Thank you

```
const StyledDatePicker = styled(DatePicker)(
({ theme }) => `
.MuiOutlinedInput-input: {
    border-radius: '15px'
}`,);

<StyledDatePicker
 label='To'
 format='dd MMM yyyy'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should target `MuiOutlinedInput-root` class

```
import { styled } from '@mui/system';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-picker';

const StyledDatePicker = styled(DatePicker)(
  ({ theme }) => `
    .MuiOutlinedInput-root {
      border-radius: 15px;
    }
  `
);

<StyledDatePicker
  label='To'
  format='dd MMM yyyy'
/>
```